# Sorting by distance in MySQL

Tags: sql, distance, mysql, geolocation

I found a sample of code

```sql
SELECT *
FROM locator
WHERE SQRT(POW(X(center) - 49.843317 , 2) + POW(Y(center) - 24.026642, 2)) * 100 < radius
```

in this question [Find points within a distance using MySQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql/356830#356830).

How can I add an `ORDER BY distance` to this code?

Comment: Will this answer your question `ORDER BY SQRT(POW(X(center) - 49.843317 , 2) + POW(Y(center) - 24.026642, 2)) * 100`?

Comment: Yep! Works like a dream! Thank you Taras!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your query as following

```sql
SELECT *
FROM locator
WHERE SQRT(POW(X(center) - 49.843317, 2) + POW(Y(center) - 24.026642, 2)) * 100 < radius
ORDER BY SQRT(POW(X(center) - 49.843317, 2) + POW(Y(center) - 24.026642, 2)) * 100
```