# Calculate latitude and longitude based on distance (miles)

Tags: mysql-spatial

I have been trying to get location details based on miles with the below query,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,loc1, zipcode, latitude,longitude, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(36.0411)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-115.2163)) + sin(radians(36.0411)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM locations) AS distances WHERE DISTANCE < 20 ORDER BY distance
```

This works in my local MySQL version but the online hosting version does not work (i.e. not getting results properly) due to the MariaDB version installed there.

Ref. [Find features within given coordinates and distance using MySQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-features-within-given-coordinates-and-distance-using-mysql/31629#31629)

Comment: local MySQL version (5.7.33) and online hosting MySQL details as Server type: MariaDB, Server version: 10.5.20-MariaDB-cll-lve-log - MariaDB Server